# Regressão logística com variável não binária

Tags: r

Eu preciso fazer um classificador com regressão logística para classificar essa variável categórica que pode ter 14 valores diferentes. Alguém sabe se é possível fazer isso com glm() ou se tenho que usar outra função (e qual)?

Comment: Aqui tem um artigo mto bom: http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/r/dae/mlogit.htm, com exemplo

Comment: Regressão logística é basicamente para respostas com apenas dois resultados ex:0 e 1, então para esse seu problema aconselho a usar um modelo de classificação para melhor representar seu modelo.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Por definição, regressão logística só pode ser utilizada para ajustar modelos onde a resposta é dicotômica: sim e não, sucesso e fracasso, macho e fêmea.

Um conjunto de dados cuja variável resposta é categórica com 14 níveis diferentes não pode ter um modelo de regressão logística ajustado a ele. Para isto, se utiliza a [Regressão Multinomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_logistic_regression) (não há verbete na wiki pt a respeito deste modelo estatístico).

O `R` é capaz de ajustar um modelo deste tipo através do comando `multinom`:

```
library(nnet)
?multinom
```

Entretanto, estes modelos são mais complicados de interpretar do que modelos de regressão logística. Sugiro o livro Categorical Data Analysis, do Alan Agresti, como uma fonte de consulta. É um livro excelente na parte teórica e razoavelmente didático. Ele tem pelo menos um capítulo inteiro dedicado à análise deste tipo de modelo.

Além disso, 14 níveis é um número bastante elevado de níveis. Eu nunca ajustei um modelo multinomial com tantos níveis assim. Não sei como um modelo destes se comportaria ou se sequer ele seria ajustado, pois podem haver problemas de estabilidade numérica. Imagino que se o tamanho amostral for pequeno, é possível que a taxa de Erro do Tipo II 
aumente, principalmente se os estimadores tiverem erro padrão alto.

Comment: Muito obrigada! É um trabalho da faculdade em que o professor especificou os tipos análises que queria que fizéssemos. Acho que vou enviar um e-mail para ele e confirmar se é isso mesmo. Obrigada!